# Improper integral or should i solve it?

Tags: improper-integrals

The problem is:

[image]

But as u can see, answers dont ask me to solve it, so i sure that, there`re another way to get the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by noticing that as $x\to\infty$,

$$\frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt[3]{\sin x}}{x^{5/3}+x\cos x}\sim x^{-7/6}$$

So it converges as $x\to\infty$ by p-series.  It should then be obvious that it must be positive, since the integrand is positive over the values, so...

Comment: @МузаффарШакаров No, I wouldn't compute $-6/x^{1/6}$ from $0$ to infinity.  I wouldn't compute anything at all.  Instead, the p-series says that$$\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^p}\ dx$$converges if $p>1$.  That is true here.